# QML Translation of Properties

Tags: python, qml, translation, pyside2

I know the translation process in QML for strings. But is there a way to translate QML properties completely with QML functions? I am working with PySide2 and I would need to translate properties defined on Python and QML side. As a minimalistic example without translation functions yet:

**main. py**

```
class example_model(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()

    @Property(str, constant=True)
    def python_property(self):
        return "Example String"

def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    model = example_model( parent=context)
    context.setContextProperty("exampleModel", model)
    engine.load(QUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(lambda: None)), "main.qml"))))

    return app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 200
    height: 400
    visible: true
    property string qmlProperty: "exampleString"

    Text{
        text: QT_TR_NOOP(exampleModel.python_property)
    }
    Text{
        text: QT_TR_NOOP(root.qmlProperty)
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it that those two properties (`python_property` and `qmlProperty`) are correctly detected by Qt's lupdate function or any other function, respectively. I need a dynamic translation, so the `engine.retranslate()` function will be used.

Comment: First of all, `QT_TR_NOOP` is, as the name says, a no-operation, so the way you are using it here will not do anything. You should put it around `"exampleString"` to have lupdate detect it. And I think you can complete your quest by putting `qsTr` for the two bindings instead of `QT_TR_NOOP`, but not 100% sure there. It worth noting that lupdate puts `main.qml` as the context, so you should take care of where the `QT_TR_NOOP` and `qsTr` are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation is similar to QML only that to use the python translation you have to use qsTranslate where you must pass the context (name of the python class) since it differs from the context of qml (name of the .qml file).

On the other hand it seems that the OP does not understand the operation of QT_TR_NOOP so it is advisable to review the docs.

Using the following example I will show the translation process:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtCore import (
    Property,
    QCoreApplication,
    QObject,
    Qt,
    QTimer,
    QTranslator,
    QUrl,
)
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
QML_DIRECTORY = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "qml"
TRANSLATIONS_DIR = CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "translations"


class PythonModel(QObject):
    def python_property(self):
        return self.tr("Python Example String")

    pythonProperty = Property(str, fget=python_property, constant=True)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    py_tranlator = QTranslator()
    res = py_tranlator.load(os.fspath(TRANSLATIONS_DIR / "py.qm"))
    assert res

    qml_tranlator = QTranslator()
    res = qml_tranlator.load(os.fspath(TRANSLATIONS_DIR / "qml.qm"))
    assert res

    python_model = PythonModel(app)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("pythonModel", python_model)

    filename = os.fspath(QML_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    ok = False

    def handle_timeout():
        nonlocal ok
        if ok:
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(py_tranlator)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(qml_tranlator)
        else:
            QCoreApplication.removeTranslator(py_tranlator)
            QCoreApplication.removeTranslator(qml_tranlator)

        engine.retranslate()

        ok = not ok

    timer = QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=handle_timeout)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    property string qmlProperty: qsTr("QML Example String")

    width: 200
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Column {
        Text {
            text: qsTranslate("pythonModel", pythonModel.pythonProperty)
        }

        Text {
            text: root.qmlProperty
        }

    }

}
```

```
├── main.py
├── qml
│   └── main.qml
└── translations
    ├── py.qm
    ├── py.ts
    ├── qml.qm
    └── qml.ts
```

1. Generate the .ts using pyside2-lupdate and lupdate:

   ```
   pyside2-lupdate main.py -ts translations/py.ts
   lupdate qml/main.qml -ts translations/qml.ts
   ```
2. Add the translations using Qt Linguist tool.
3. Generate the .qm using lrelease:

   ```
   lrelease translations/py.ts translations/py.qm
   lrelease translations/qml.ts translations/qml.qm
   ```
4. Then you have to load both translations.

If you don't want to have multiple .ts or .qm then you can use lconvert to join the files.

<sub>You can find the complete example [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/68769134).</sub>